# Check if a String in a set starts with a String of another set

Tags: java, string, set

Assume we have two sets of Strings named A and B. Now I want to check if any String of set B starts with any String from set A: It does not matter which of the strings match, is just be a boolean method.

Of course, I can run through set A and set B and use the startsWith method of String:

```
for (String a: A)
  for (String b: B)
     if (b.startsWith(a))
          return true;
return false;
```

But I wonder if there is any faster way?

Comment: Where is your codes ?

Comment: My check does not depend on the order of A or B.

Comment: @JFMeier Yeah. Order doesn't  not matter.

Comment: Do you know anything else about the strings (e.g. their length)?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `TreeSet A` instead of `Set A` you should use something like this (I don't check this example):

```
for (String b: B) {
    String a = A1.ceiling(b);
    if(a != null && a.startsWith(b)) 
       return true;
}
return false;
```

It's should be faster if you often use this function.